# How to filter data using dropdown option

Tags: php, mysql, filter, html.dropdownlistfor

I try to filter some data using dropdown option. When user select year/division and click filter button, it suppose to read all row from database that contain the value. This is as far as I can go and it didn't work. Really hope someone can help me.

```
 if (isset($_GET['do']))
{
    if($_GET['do'] == 'filter')
    {
        if( empty($_POST['key_year']))
        {
            redirect("list.php");
        }
        else
        {   
            $_SESSION['key_year'] = $_POST['key_year'];         
            $_SESSION['key_division'] = $_POST['key_division'];         
        }
    }
    else if($_GET['do'] == 'clear')
    {
        unset($_SESSION['key_year']);
        redirect("list.php");
    }
    else
    {}  
}
$limit = 10;    
$page = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;   
$end = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? ($limit * $_GET['page']) : $limit;
$offset = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? ($limit * $_GET['page']) - $limit : 0;
$start = $offset +1;
$next = $page + 1;
$prev = $page - 1;
$key_year = ( isset($_SESSION['key_year']) ) ? $_SESSION['key_year'] : '';
$key_year = ( isset($_SESSION['key_division']) ) ? $_SESSION['key_division'] : '';

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_perfomance ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY `p_aid` ASC";
$sql .= " LIMIT $offset, $limit";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

$sql2="SELECT COUNT(p_aid) AS total FROM tbl_perfomance ";
if(isset($key_year) && isset($key_division))
{
    $sql2 .= "WHERE p_year LIKE '%$key_year%' AND p_division LIKE '%$key_division%'";
}
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2);
$getRec = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2);
//total
$rowCount=$getRec['total'];
$end = ($end > $rowCount) ? $rowCount : $end;
$total_page = ceil($rowCount/$limit);

$for_start = ( $page <= 2 ) ? 1 : $page - 2;
$for_stop_tmp = $page + 2;
$for_stop  = ( $for_stop_tmp > $total_page ) ? $total_page : $page + 2;
```

This is the form.

```
            <form name="filter" action="list.php?do=filter" method="GET">
                    </label>
                    <label style="color:darkgreen;float:left;width:11%" align="left">
                        Division
                        <select name="key_division">
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            <option value="ITNT">ITNT</option>
                           <option value="ITP">ITP</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>     -->                
                    <label style="color:darkgreen;float:left;width:11%" align="left">                           
                        Year        
                        <select name="key_year">
                            <option value="all">All</option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label style="color:darkgreen;float:left;width:11%" align="left">
                    </label><br>
                        <input class="button_green" type="submit" value="Filter &raquo;" /> 

            </form>
```

Comment: try to echo your sql query and test it in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I feel you just adding conditions for paging sql not for the content sql

Try to change your code something like this so that you have proper `$sql1` and `$sql2`.

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_perfomance ";

$sql2="SELECT COUNT(p_aid) AS total FROM tbl_perfomance ";
if(isset($key_year) && isset($key_division))
{
    $sql2 .= "WHERE p_year LIKE '%$key_year%' AND p_division LIKE '%$key_division%'";
    $sql1 .= "WHERE p_year LIKE '%$key_year%' AND p_division LIKE '%$key_division%'";
}

$sql .= "ORDER BY `p_aid` ASC";
$sql .= " LIMIT $offset, $limit";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

$rs2=mysql_query($sql2);
$getRec = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2);
```

once you do it than echo both the queries and run them directly in php myadmin or any other mysql tool to check that these are working.